# How to find using directives

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2013, using-directives

I wold Like To Know How To Easily Find using directives eg.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
```

I am Learning how to use VS2013 & c#,so i Google a lot of things.Some times i get a chard of code and VS says:

```
The type or namespace name 'somenamespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Then i Google a lot to find the correct using namespace ,time wasted.
is there a library i can search for it,
or a video that would show me how to find these things?

Comment: (CTRL + .)  VS ShortCut key.provided the assembly is referenced in project.and there are tools like Resharper which might help.

Comment: Look up the type in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 suggest you suitable namespaces even without any additional tools or libraries.

Just point to class name that needs additional using directive and you will see small rectangle below which will bring out a popup. On the picture you can see both ReSharper and VS popups.

You can also check the class name in the MSDN. It always show you the namespace for current class like:

> Namespace:  System.IO
>
> Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

[image: VS popup sample]

Comment: My VS2013 dose not show the question mark thing,but as soon as you start typing "stream" Intellisense shows in a list of things below it:"Stream (in System.IO)","Class System.IO.Stream".It dose not show it when you copy&paste. but its faster to find than Google.For some reason i find AutoIt's help file more helpful for that language than i find Microsoft's help for c#.In fact this site is more helpful with c# then that Microsoft THING!?At least Intellisense is nifty!

Answer (score 2):

Use resharper. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

This is one of the fantastic features I like resharper for. Once you install resharper, it will automatically popup while typing and also you can force invoke the type importer with `Ctrl + Space`.

There is an example, notice how it automatically found the namespace-
[image]

Comment: Actually Visual Studio does this by itself. What Resharper adds on top of it is if the assembly the class is in is not refrenced by your project but the assembly does reside in the GAC it will add the `using` statement to your file and add the assembly to the list of referenced assemblies in your project.

Comment: im Using visual studio express 2013 so resharper will not work.+Its way to expensive ,unless you get a "Free copy" from TPB or something..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain actually I don't think it does **exactly** what Resharper offers. You have to: 1) type **the whole** type name 2) press CTRL + . or whatever 3) press ENTER. With Resharper you just have to: 1) start typing the class name **without the need to complete it** 2) choose it 3) press ENTER. When you need a class with a name that is far too long to know it by heart then Resharper saves a lot of time. If I've missed something I'd be happy if you tell me which option in Visual Studio enables the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio's `Intellisense` will assist you with this kind of problem. Just enter the type name, then press `Alt+Shift+F10` and if the type is inside any of the referenced assemblies you will get options of add a `Using Namespace` or change `TypeName` to `Namespace.TypeName`.